# SQL create table using code and populate with code

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm working on an assignment and have created my code on NotePad++ to then copy over to SSMS, however when I create a table it brings me to the default view which is manually entering the column names and data. I want to just paste my created code into the database to create the table. How do I go about this?

Also my prof has provided data to populate my tables but I can't seem to figure out where I paste his `INSERT INTO` data into?

Also, for some reason I attempted to create a new query in the database i created for the assignment and pasted the code into that, but the tables don't show up even if I execute them in the Tables drop down.

Code for notepad++

```
CREATE TABLE tblMajors
(
    MajorCode varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    MajorDescription varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE tblInstructors
(
    InstructorNumber int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    InstructorFirst varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    InstructorLast varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ContractStatus varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber bigint NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE tblStudents
(
    StudentNumber int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    StudentFirst varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    StudentLast varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    MajorCode varchar(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblMajors (MajorCode),
)

CREATE TABLE tblCourses
(
    CourseCode varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    CourseDescription varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE tblGrades
(
    StudentNumber bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblStudents (StudentNumber),
    CourseCode varchar(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblCourses (CourseCode),
    Grade int NOT NULL,
    IntructorNumber int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblInstructors (IntructorNumber),
    PRIMARY KEY (StudentNumber, CourseCode)
)
```

Comment: "I can't seem to figure out where I paste his INSERT INTO data into?"...click New Query on the toolbar, then paste the insert statements into the blank window which is created, then click Execute on the toolbar (or press F5) to run them.

Comment: "tables don't show up even if I execute them in the Tables drop down."...not sure what this actually means. To execute CREATE TABLE statements, follow the exact same process as for the INSERT statements in my comment above. Both are SQL code, and both need to be executed. (P.S. any new tables you added by executing create table statments won't show in the Object Explorer GUI unless you right click on the "tables" folder in your database (in the Object explorer) and then click "Refresh".)